# getting the unspent bitcoins based on bitcoin address

Tags: website-integration

im new to bitcoin and want to find out which is the best API or way for getting the bitcoin balance of a bitcoin address for any bitcoin address in C#

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the API of a block explorer. Several provide such an API and some have wrapper libraries for C#.

For example the blockchain.info blockchain explorer has such an [API](https://blockchain.info/api) and has a C# wrapper as well. Consult their [Blockchain Data API](https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api) which explains how to get the balance (among other data) from an address. More specifically, you need to call the following (HTTP) API:

```
https://blockchain.info/address/$bitcoin_address?format=json
```

The result is a json object and "final_balance" is what you need.

If you use the C# wrapper you can find an example on how to get the balance of an address (and many other things) [here](https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-csharp/blob/master/docs/blockexplorer.md).

Alternatively, you could query a bitcoin node directly. The easiest way to do that in C# would be to use a [wrapper library](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib).

Comment: ok, i'll look into the Blockchain Data API and see if I can figure it out. Thanks

Comment: I edited the answer to add the API needed plus an example using the C# wrapper library.